# New button on a list causes entire screen to disable/grey out

Tags: list, sharepoint-on-prem, new-item

Clicking the 'New' item button on any list with a 'Hyperlink or Picture' column causes the entire list to be disabled/grayed out.

Seems to have started after installing the June 2023 patch.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that came with the latest patch for june 2023.

> After installing June 2023 CU for SharePoint Server 2019 we received a
> couple of calls on a problem that creating or updating list items in
> modern experience not possible after June 2023 CU for SharePoint
> Server 2019. This affects lists and document libraries which contain
> hyperlink or picture columns.

[Trending issue: SP2019 – creating or updating list items in modern experience not possible after June 2023 CU](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/06/23/trending-issue-sp2019-creating-or-updating-list-items-in-modern-experience-not-possible-after-june-2023-cu/)

The current work-around until a new patch witch fixes the issue is to use either the classic experience and/or quick edit.